# Spark DataFrame mapPartitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to proceed distributed calculation on Spark DataFrame invoking some arbitrary (not SQL) logic on chunks of DataFrame. 
I did:

```
def some_func(df_chunk):
    pan_df = df_chunk.toPandas()
    #whatever logic here

df = sqlContext.read.parquet(...)
result = df.mapPartitions(some_func)
```

Unfortunatelly it leads to:

> AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'toPandas'

I expected to have spark DataFrame object within each map invocation, instead I got 'itertools.chain'. Why? And how to overcome this?

Comment: PySpark is using itertools.chain to pass data to the mapPartition and thus you are passing this object to the function which it does not recognize.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> columns = df.columns
>>> df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter: [pd.DataFrame(list(iter), columns=columns)])
```

Comment: Where's the 'result' ? how do you call some_func as in the OP?